# SOAP call variable with sigle quote

Tags: php, soap, quote

I am sending a object to a web service that requires a value to be in single quote.  How do I input my variable with a single quote?

```
Value' => '750'  variable is $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['weight']
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar, by using the below, not SOAP but idea is the same:

```
 $Value = "'".$_SESSION['order'].$_SESSION[$counter].$_SESSION['weight']."'";
```

Comment: cant do that because the word value is a namespace in the SOAP call so it has to be exact.